# How do I store output from an API endpoint that contains date + time in an array, using PHP?

Tags: php, api

I am a beginner, learning PHP. I am trying to adapt PHP code written by someone else, which retrieves data from an API and displays it in a PHP app on a web server.

Here is an example of code from a 3rd party app I'm trying to manipulate:

```
<tbody>
                        <?php foreach($citadelData->result() as $row) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row->corporationname; ?></td>
                                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->sys_name; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->con_name; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->reg_name; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->services; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->ConsumesFuel; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->typename; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->stateTimerStart; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->stateTimerEnd; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->fuelExpires; ?></td>                                  
                            </tr>
```

For the $row->fuelExpires; variable, the API endpoint returns a date formatted like so:

```
2017-12-16 15:00:00
```

I am trying to understand how I would store this data so I may discard parts of it and format it on the screen differently. I THINK I want to use an array, but I am not sure how to store that data as an array.

The end result I am trying to achieve would be to turn the above date into

```
67 days, 15 hours
```

Should I try to store the date in an array so as to be able to manipulate the data to turn it into my final format, or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: create a new Date object and you can get expected values. You probably want this http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to get an interval as number of days you would need two dates, so I am assuming that in addition to the *fuelExpires* date you also have some sort of fuel start date.

Based on the code you posted I am also assuming that this data is read from a database, row by row, and for each row its fields are displayed. The point is that if the *fuelExpires* field is read as a DateTime object then you can just use the PHP *date_diff* function:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Alternatively, if *fuelExpires* is a text string, you can create a DateTime object as also illustrated in the code snipet. By the way, I got the code snippet from the PHP manual which you can find at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

**EDIT:**

To use the current date as start data you need to do something along these lines:

```
<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime1->setTimestamp(time());

// if fuelExpires is DateTime object
$datetime2 = $row->fuelExpires;

// if fuelExpires is text string object
$datetime2 = date_create($row->fuelExpires);

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo $interval->format('%a days, %h hours');
?>
```

Note that this code may not be fully functional as I've typed it off the top of my head and haven't checked it.

Comment: I apologize for not specifying - but the start date would be the current time and date. The "67 days, 15 hours" time is the remaining time until the object runs out of fuel.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.